# Can I place a product in multiple categories?

Tags: magento-1.9

Like a same product in new arrivals and featured products etc...will this cause duplication?

Comment: Simple answer: yes?! Just tick the categories you would like to have the product in. Catalog > Manage Products > select product > Categories. The product does not get duplicated.

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Using the category structure you can achieve this. Also on duplication Magento uses "canonical" tags so content duplication is avoided.

You can manage this from the product edit screen and associate to categories there, Or via catalog manage categories and assign products to the category from there.

Comment: has Magento always done the canonical tags? Or is this relatively a new feature?

Comment: I think it was introduced in 1.7 but i could be wrong.